# Conditional probability using different information

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, conditional-probability, latent-variable

$X$ is a hidden variable and is connected by two probability distributions $p(x|y_1)$, $p(x|y_2)$, to $y_{1,2}$, measurable variables, while $x \in \{0,1\}$.  How can I derive $p(x|y_1, y_2)$?

**First case:**
Graph for first case:
$$y_2, p(y_2), p(y_2|x), p(x|y_2) \xleftarrow{measurement_2} x \xrightarrow{measurement_1} p(x|y_1)$$

- I have no information about $p(y_1)$ and $P(y_1|x)$, I don't even have $y_1$. All I have about it is the only value $p(x|y_1)$.
- This is the simplest case, because I have $p(x|y_2)$, $p(y_2)$, $p(y_2|x)$ and $y_2$.

**Second case:**
Graph for second case:
$$p(x|y_2) \xleftarrow{measurement_2} x \xrightarrow{measurement_1} p(x|y_1)$$

- I have no information about $p(y_1)$, $P(y_1|x)$, $y_1$. All I have about it is the only value $p(x|y_1)$.
- I have no information about $p(y_2)$, $P(y_2|x)$, $y_2$. All I have about it is the only value $p(x|y_2)$.

I tried to use Bayes formula for the first case, using $p(x|y_1)$ as prior probability to recalculate $p(x|y_2)$, but it often yields $p>1$, so I think I have fundamental misunderstanding. For case 2 I have no idea what to do.
How can I get $p(x|y_1, y_2)$ for both cases?

**Update**:
If it could help: $y_1=x+noise_1$ and $y_2=x+noise_2$. $p(x=1|y1)$ and $p(x=1|y2)$ were definitely calculated using Bayes theorem and now we have them as input (how can you see in cases description, with some info about densities hidden from us).
Is there any way to make better inference about $x$ given all information I have?

Comment: If you do not observe $y_1$ or $(y_1,y_2)$ why is it relevant to compute the full conditional? And without information about the joint distribution of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ and of the dependence graph between $X$ and the two random variables, there is no unique solution for $p(x|y_1, y_2)$

Comment: @Xi'an it is relevant because I need to infer is x 0 or 1 given this info. You said there is no unique solution. Can you propose any way to improve probability value even if solution won't be unique. I think if $p(x|y_1)=0.5$ and $p(x|y_2)=0.9$ I think I should treat $x=1$. Is any way to formalize this?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by $p(x|y_1)=0.5$. Do you mean $p(x=0|y_1)=0.5$ and is it constant, ie independent of the realisation of $Y_1$?

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry for confusing, I meant $p(x=1|y_1) = 0.5$ and yes, it's a constant. If it could help: $y_1 = x + noise_1$ and $y_2 = x + noise_2$. $p(x=1|y_1)$ and $p(x=1|y_2)$ were definitely calculated using Bayes theorem and now we have them as input (how can you see in cases description, with some info about densities hidden from us).